# My HeightFeet element in xml is not displaying

Tags: xml, xslt

Based on my xml code, I want to convert the HeightFeet number into inches. 
I also want to check that the HeightFeet is not less than 48 inches and not greater than 95 inches. 
How do I do this?

**Desired output**

```
<ext:Respondent>
    <nc:PersonSexCode>F </nc:PersonSexCode>
    <nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
        <nc:MeasureText>60</nc:MeasureText>
        <nc:MeasureUnitText>inches</nc:MeasureUnitText>
        <nc:LengthUnitCode>INH</nc:LengthUnitCode>
    </nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
        <nc:PersonWeightMeasure>
        <nc:MeasureText>130</nc:MeasureText>
        <nc:MeasureUnitText>pounds</nc:MeasureUnitText>
        <nc:WeightUnitCode>LBR</nc:WeightUnitCode>
    </nc:PersonWeightMeasure>
</ext:Respondent>
```

**Current output without Height**

```
<nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
<nc:MeasureText>NaN</nc:MeasureText>
<nc:MeasureUnitText>inches</nc:MeasureUnitText>
<nc:LengthUnitCode>INH</nc:LengthUnitCode>
```

**xml code**

```
<Party ID="1116666" InternalPartyID="1610656384">
    <Gender Word="F">Female</Gender>
    <HeightFeet>5</HeightFeet>
    <WeightPounds>130</WeightPounds>
    <EyeColor Word="BLU">Blue</EyeColor>
</Party>
```

**My edited simplified xslt code**

```
    <nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
   <nc:MeasureText>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="HeightFeet"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="(HeightFeet*12) + HeightInches "/>
    </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </nc:MeasureText>
   <nc:MeasureUnitText>
      <xsl:text>inches</xsl:text>
   </nc:MeasureUnitText>
   <nc:LengthUnitCode>
   <xsl:text>INH</xsl:text>
   </nc:LengthUnitCode>
</nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
```

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: Please post a **complete** stylesheet - including the namespace declarations - so that we can try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I saw your suggested edit to my answer. You should add that to your question instead. The reason you're getting `NaN` (not a number) is because `HeightInches` doesn't exist in your input. You will need to test it to see if it's there and if it is a number (you could use `test="number(HeightInches)"` in an `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`/`xsl:when`).

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not outputting is that you're trying to add `HeightInches` but there is no `HeightInches` in your input.

Looking at your previous questions I noticed that the version of XSLT you're using is 3.0. If you're truly using a 3.0 (or 2.0) processor, try changing your `xsl:if` to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="inches" select="if (HeightInches castable as xs:double) then HeightFeet * 12 + HeightInches else HeightFeet * 12"/>
<xsl:if test="($inches > 48) and (95 > $inches)">
    <PersonHeightMeasure>
        <MeasureText>
            <xsl:value-of select="$inches"/>
        </MeasureText>
        <MeasureUnitText>
            <xsl:text>inches</xsl:text>
        </MeasureUnitText>
        <LengthUnitCode>
            <xsl:text>INH</xsl:text>
        </LengthUnitCode>
    </PersonHeightMeasure>
</xsl:if>
```

Note: You might have to declare the namespace `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in your stylesheet to use this answer.

Comment: `+ HeightInches` is outside the THEN statement. Rather `then (HeightFeet * 12 + HeightInches)`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller - Works fine as-is in Saxon. However, I'll just remove the parens entirely as they aren't really needed.

Comment: My comment related to something the OP had said (now deleted) - but it was only guessing anyway. +1